# rails ラジオボタンのバリデーションについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails

### やりたいこと

２つあるラジオボタンのどちらにもチェックが入っていない場合、バリデーションでエラーメッセージを表示するようにしたい。

### 設定

view

```
= form_with(model: @info) do |f|
  = render 'shared/errors', object: @info
  .field
    = f.radio_button :class, 1
    = f.label :classification, "#{t '.class1'}", value: 1
  .field
    = f.radio_button :class, 2
    = f.label :classification, "#{t '.class2'}", value: 2
  .button-field
    = f.submit "#{t '.title'}", class: "btn btn-primary"
```

modelカラム

```
t.integer "class" ## 1:google 2:yahoo
```

### 質問

```
validates :class, presence:true
```

ノーマルなやり方だとエラーメッセージが出ません。
ググっても解決できず・・・
ご教示お願いします。

Comment: ログにリクエストで送信されるパラメータが表示されているはずです。その内容を質問を編集して追記してください

Answer (score 0):

`inclusion` を使うとできそうな気がします。

コードは多分、こんな感じになるかと思います。

```
validates : class, inclusion: {in: [1, 2]}
```

参考: https://qiita.com/shunhikita/items/cb0a7b92c62c10135791

Comment: ありがとうございます。やってみたんですが、できませんでした。。。他のやり方があるのか、探してみます。

Comment: あら、そうでしたか...。検証せずに回答してしまい失礼いたしましたmm

Answer (score 0):

カラム名にclassというRubyのキーワードを使ってしまっているので、動かないのだと思われます。
p_classなど別の名前にした上で、inclusionでバリデートすると動くと思います。